# getting wrong value from Cookie in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use belowe code for add Cooki :

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("HozhanSecurityCode");
        cookie.Value = "1234";

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

And to get Cookie use this code :

```
            var httpCookie = Request.Cookies["SecurityCode"];
        string SecurityInput = httpCookie.Value.ToString();
```

But I getting '1453' instead of '1234' .

what's problem ?

Comment: HozhanSecurityCode != SecurityCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie name inside httpcookie constructor and key of inside Request.Cookie object should be the same.